# Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-contentprovider, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an application, which uses Facebook SDK for sharing its content. It works fine on APIs > 17, but crashes on APIs 16 and 17. Here's a log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4548)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
        android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
        applicationId "com.XXXX.XXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile('com.github.lowlevel-studios:storo:1.1.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.martinwithaar:PinchToZoom:6ed982fe58'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.28.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:2.0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.ac-opensource:MarkerBuilder:v1.0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's my FacebookProvider in Manifest.xml:

```
  <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Does anybody have any ideas? There are several similar questions already created here, but none of them was solved.

Comment: so did you figure out?